# CSS3 Columns are not displaying on IPad and IPhone

Tags: iphone, css, ipad, css-multicolumn-layout

I'm using CSS3 Columns like

```
.Content {
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease;
    transition: all .2s ease;
}
.List {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 0px;
    -moz-column-gap: 0px;
    column-gap: 0px;
    display: block !important;
}
```

and my html looks like this.

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 List">
  <div class="Content col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     My content
  </div>
</div>
```

I checked my iPad and iPhone diplay by Chrome development tool, and it works fine. However, real iPad and iPhone not showing anythings. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a long trip, I found a solution about this problem. 
What I want to achieve was made my cards look like ***pinterest***. And I used [Lightweight Responsive Pinterest Layout with jQuery - Waterfall](http://www.jqueryscript.net/layout/Lightweight-Responsive-Pinterest-Layout-with-jQuery-Waterfall.html).

Answer (score 1):

Non fully supporting browsers that use the prefix `-webkit-` have some missing elements which cannot be used.

> Webkit browsers do have equivalent support for the non-standard `-webkit-column-break-*` properties to accomplish the same result (but only the `auto` and `always` values). Firefox does not support `break-*`.

[CanIUse - Columns](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn)

This pretty much states that webkit browsers (such as those on an iPhone or iPad) do not have even partial support for `column-break` and therefore you will need to find an alternative such as using JavaScript or having a fallback in CSS.

Columnizer is a good jQuery plugin which creates the same effect but using JavaScript.

[Columnizer jQuery Plugin](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have one question. I download that plugin and apply it to my div like `$('.List').columnize({ columns: 3 });`. And it works what you said. However, **it's hard to handle breaking point.** I want to make my div looks like _pinterest_. Any suggestion about this? Thank you.